# How can I set Users that are in the same League as a variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

I am building a Fantasy Football web game in RoR whereby a user can sign up, create a club and play in a league with their friends.

I've built a conversations area for users in the same league to message each other individually and can get it to work with all users (@users = User.all) however, I am not sure how to make the link through to the club table which contains the users league_id.

How do I do this?

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_secure_password

  has_many :messages
  has_many :conversations, :primary_key => :sender_id
  has_one :club
  has_one :league_chat
end

class Club < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :league
    has_many :players
end

class League < ApplicationRecord
    has_one :league_chat
    has_many :clubs
    has_many :users, through: :clubs
end

class ConversationsController < ApplicationController
  # before_action :authenticate_user

  before_action :user_confirm_logged_in

  def index
    @users = current_user.club.league.users
    @conversations = Conversation.all
  end

  def create
    if Conversation.between(params[:sender_id], params[:recipient_id]).present?
      @conversation = Conversation.between(params[:sender_id], params[:recipient_id]).first
    else
      @conversation = Conversation.create!(conversation_params)
    end
    redirect_to conversation_messages_path(@conversation)
  end

  private

  def conversation_params
    params.permit(:sender_id, :recipient_id, :league_id)
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

So you can do

```
all_league_users = current_user.club.league.users
```

That works provided you have...

```
class League
  has_many :clubs
  has_many :users, through: :clubs
end

class Club
  belongs_to :league
end
```

Comment: It then says League is not defined?

Comment: Have you got `class Club; belongs_to :league` ?  See my edit.

Comment: Yes and it still says it.

Answer (score 0):

The following will give you all the users from the same league:

```
User.where(league_id: your_variable)
```

Replace `your_variable` with the actual variable which contains the `id` of the league you want to find users for.

Comment: It won't because I don't have a "league_id" column in Users, unless I make Users belong_to Leagues.

Answer (score 0):

```
users = Club.where(league_id: the_league_you_want.id).all.map(&:user).uniq
```